# Copperplate gothic light not working in firefox 21.0

Tags: php, html, css, fonts, firebug

I am using a copperplate gothic font in my website but it is not working properly in firefox 21.0. Instead it is working correct in firefox 20.0.1. What might be the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try google Web Fonts www.google.com/webfonts‎. This will work in all the browsers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

```
{
font-family: Copperplate / Copperplate Gothic Light;
}
```

That should work. If its now working though you have put the correct code. Please try Google WebFonts. www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Balthazar is the best google web fonts alternative for Copperplate gothic.
Here is a sample code to use google web fonts.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Balthazar">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Balthazar', serif;
        font-size: 48px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>This looks like Copperplate font in all browsers.!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```